# Single downvote results in a single upvote if downvote removed

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, upvotes

I have noticed the following behavior and I was wondering if this is by design:

I down-vote a question/answer and I am the lone down-vote. The OP improves the question/answer so I wish to remove down-vote. The counter does not go to 0, instead it goes to +1 (a single upvote).

This differs from the behavior where a question/answer has multiple down-votes. An added down-vote by me subtracts from the total count, while the removal of that down-vote adds to the total down-vote count (given negative numbers). I down-vote a post at -2, it goes to -3. I remove the down-vote and the count goes back to -2.

Why does the removal of my single down-vote result in a single up-vote? Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you switch your vote instead of just reversing it? Another user could have also voted at the same time you reversed your vote. The system does work as you expect it should

Comment: Switch instead of reversing? I didn't realize there were two actions available. I clicked the up arrow thinking the subtraction/addition would occur as it should. the behavior is something I've noticed many times, so it is unlikely to be the coincidence you mention @BradleyDotNET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't just *reverse* your vote, you *switched* your vote.

Starting from the downvote position, you can do one of two things:

- Click the "Upvote" arrow as you did. This

  1. Reverses your downvote (score now 0)
  2. Applies an upvote (score now 1)
- Click the "Downvote" arrow again. Since you can't vote twice, this:

  1. Reverses your downvote (score now 0)

So the system worked as intended. If you simply wish to remove a vote, click the button again.

Comment: Ah! I did not realize that I could click the down-vote again. Thanks!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Note that there are other actions on the site that work like this. "Favorites", Comment votes, and chat stars are among them.

Comment: I wonder how many other users are going around upvoting posts thinking that they're just reversing their downvotes...

Comment: @TheSuitIsBlackNot It's sort of apparent because the corresponding arrow is highlighted if you have an active vote. I clicked the wrong arrow when trying to reverse a downvote before, and immediately noticed my mistake because the upvote arrow was highlighted.

Comment: @RetoKoradi The OP has >10k reputation and has apparently never noticed that. I'm guessing they're not the only one.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot +1 for that comment, I too have just noticed that - I have never seen that functionality anywhere on any other site, not clear is an understatement